# Slow Select option rendering in Internet explorer with large number of items - Classic ASP

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, asp-classic

So basically I have a classic ASP web page. I have a form dropdown box which is populated with account codes from the database (around 4000 of them).
In Chrome this renders fine.
In Internet Explorer its painfully slow to render the dropdown box with populated database fields.

I have done some research and thought the issue may be to do with looping through the recordset each time, so converted the code to Getrows but its still the same. I have also tried just listing the option rather than the option value as well. It will render, its just slow, how can this be made quicker ? I am using Internet explorer 11.

```
 <select name="account1" id="account1">

 <% If no_rows Then
Else     

 For X = 0 to Ubound(TheArray,2)%>
 <option value="<%response.write(TheArray(arraykeycode,x))%>"><%response.write(TheArray    (arraykeycode,x))%></option>
next
end if%>
            </select>
```

Comment: did you check, if you have the same problem if you serve an html page with the same amount of option values? If you, you can eliminate ASP as a problem source

Comment: Just checked, its faster rending in html alone

Comment: @Emma You created a static HTML page with a `<select>` containing 4000 `<option>` tags and tested that? Personally I'm with Paul 4000 `<option>` tags in a `<select>` tag is poor development, you should consider using an JQuery AutoComplete or some similar mechanism to filter the list without sacrificing ui responsiveness.

Comment: @lankymart Yes I did. This way is more usable for the end user as they can see a list of account codes, it validates correct entries and they can just type to enter the account code aswell.

Comment: @Emma Sorry but I can't see how 4000+ `<option>` tags in a `<select>` can ever be considered *"usable"* but glad Paul's solution has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to minimise the amount of text going to the page, and, to be honest, 4000 items in a drop down list is poor development. Try limiting the values that are going to the drop down list by filtering them (by another drop down for instance).

Perhaps your best bet here would be to use the `GetString` function to render the string. This method of the `RecordSet` object is similar to `GetRows`, except you can specify a filler in between each element in a row and the start and end of the string. [Have a look here](http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/Formatting-ADO-GetString/) for clarification.

**-- EDIT --**

Just to take this post a stage further, here's a small example:

```vbs
Dim sql, rs, str
sql = _
    "SELECT " & _
        "'<option value=""' + CAST([id] AS VARCHAR) + '"">' + " & _
            "[description] + '</option>' " & _
    "FROM " & _
        "myLookupList "
set rsData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sqlString, Application("conn"), 0, 1, 1
str = rs.GetString()
...
...
```

```html
<select id="myLookup">
    <%= str %>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - Incorrect syntax near '<'. Line 113 (the sql statement)

  Set cnnSimple = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnSimple.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=;Initial Catalog=;Data Source="

    Dim sql, rs, str
sql = "SELECT " & _
        "'<option value=""' + CAST([keycode] AS VARCHAR) + '""> + " & _
         "[keycode] + '</option>' " & _
          "FROM " & _
        "Customer "
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.Open sql, cnnSimple, 0, 1, 1

Comment: Ah! Yes - missed an apostrophe out of the `SELECT` statement in the line `"'<option value=""' + CAST([id] AS VARCHAR) + '""> + " & _`, it should be `"'<option value=""' + CAST([id] AS VARCHAR) + '"">' + " & _` (notice the apostrophe after the closing `>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, page time has gone from 4.34 seconds to 1.61 seconds.